# Querying Athena tables in AWS Glue Python Shell

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Python Shell Jobs was introduced in AWS Glue. They mentioned:

> You can now use Python shell jobs, for example, to submit SQL queries to services such as ... Amazon Athena ...

Ok. We have an example to read data from Athena tables [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html):

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

persons = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
             database="legislators",
             table_name="persons_json")
print("Count: ", persons.count())
persons.printSchema()
# TODO query all persons
```

However, it uses Spark instead of Python Shell. There are no such libraries that are normally available with Spark job type and I have an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue.transforms'

How can I rewrite the code above to make it executable in the Python Shell job type?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question?

Comment: I solved this issue for me. Check out my answer to the question that I posted just now, please.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, Python Shell type has its own limited set of built-in [libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#python-shell-supported-library).

I only managed to achieve my goal using [Boto 3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) to query data and [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to read it into a dataframe.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
athena_client = boto3.client(service_name='athena', region_name='us-east-1')
bucket_name = 'bucket-with-csv'
print('Working bucket: {}'.format(bucket_name))

def run_query(client, query):
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={ 'Database': 'sample-db' },
        ResultConfiguration={ 'OutputLocation': 's3://{}/fromglue/'.format(bucket_name) },
    )
    return response

def validate_query(client, query_id):
    resp = ["FAILED", "SUCCEEDED", "CANCELLED"]
    response = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_id)
    # wait until query finishes
    while response["QueryExecution"]["Status"]["State"] not in resp:
        response = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_id)

    return response["QueryExecution"]["Status"]["State"]

def read(query):
    print('start query: {}\n'.format(query))
    qe = run_query(athena_client, query)
    qstate = validate_query(athena_client, qe["QueryExecutionId"])
    print('query state: {}\n'.format(qstate))

    file_name = "fromglue/{}.csv".format(qe["QueryExecutionId"])
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    return pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])

time_entries_df = read('SELECT * FROM sample-table')
```

Comment: You can bring your own libs to the python shell jobs, like this one https://pypi.org/project/PyAthena/

Comment: Your answer match almost perfectly my expectations, thank you! However, you didn't specify output file format, reading them as CSV, but actually, they are TXT. So panda cannot read them with the `pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])`. Is there any option to force the output to CSV ?

Comment: @Jérémy, In my case, the output was already in CSV format, or I don't remember the implementation details well already.

Answer (score 3):

SparkContext won't be available in Glue Python Shell. Hence you need to depend on Boto3 and Pandas to handle the data retrieval. But it comes a lot of overhead to query Athena using boto3 and poll the ExecutionId to check if the query execution got finished.

Recently awslabs released a new package called AWS Data Wrangler. It extends power of Pandas library to AWS to easily interact with Athena and lot of other AWS Services.

**Reference link:**

1. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler
2. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/master/tutorials/006%20-%20Amazon%20Athena.ipynb

**Note:** AWS Data Wrangler library wont be available by default inside Glue Python shell. To include it in Python shell, follow the instructions in following link:

https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#aws-glue-python-shell-jobs

Answer (score -1):

I have a few month using glue, i use:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

data_frame = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header","true")\
    .load(<CSVs THAT IS USING FOR ATHENA - STRING>)
```

Comment: Using the code I have `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'`.
Are you sure that your job type is "Python Shell" (not "Spark") here?

Comment: Spark mode is necessary for use spark data frames

Comment: Other way is using `select_object_content` function of s3 client of boto3, you can run SQL querys on CSVs

Comment: Thanks. It is not a problem for me to use Spark type, but I want a cost efficient solution. "Python Shell" type is much cheaper. My question was about Python Shell.

Comment: Of course, you can use boto3 on glue python shell and use sql on csv with s3 client (boto3)

Comment: That's correct. I descovered this option after I asked this question on StackOverflow. It works for me. The only concern is the code with boto3 is verbose. I would perefer to use libraries like PyAthena

Comment: Not an answer to the question. It neither works with Python Shell jobs, neither is using Athena.